# Why are these ODE's classified as d'Alembert first order ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

According to many sources and Maple itself, `d'Alembert` ode has the form

$$
    y(x) = x f(y'(x)) + g( y'(x) )
$$

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FdAlembert

This is a generalization of Clairaut's ODE  $ y(x)= x y'(x)+ g(y'(x))$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClairautsDifferentialEquation.html

Maple has a function which gives the type of an ODE. My question is, why does it say the following ODE's are d'Alembert? I do not see how these fit the pattern shown above.

### First example

```
ode:=diff(y(x),x)=y(x)/x+1/x*sqrt(y(x)*x);
DEtools:-odeadvisor(ode)
        [[_homogeneous, `class A`], _rational, _dAlembert]
```

$$
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) ={\frac {y \left( x
 \right) }{x}}+{\frac {\sqrt {y \left( x \right) x}}{x}}
$$

### Second example

```
ode:=diff(y(x),x)=exp(y(x)/x)+y(x)/x;
DEtools:-odeadvisor(ode);
     [[_homogeneous, `class A`], _dAlembert]
```

$$
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) ={{\rm e}^{{\frac {y
 \left( x \right) }{x}}}}+{\frac {y \left( x \right) }{x}}
$$

### Third example

```
ode:=diff(y(x),x)=2*x*y(x)/(x^2-y(x)^2);
DEtools:-odeadvisor(ode);
     [[_homogeneous, `class A`], _rational, _dAlembert]
```

$$
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) =2\,{\frac {y \left( x
 \right) x}{{x}^{2}- \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$

If these are really `dAlembert`, then what is the `f(y')` and `g(y')` in these ODE? I am not sure how to transform these ODE's to the general form of `dAlembert` in order to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first DE can be written as $$y = x\; \frac{2 y' + 1 \pm \sqrt{1+4y'}}{2}$$
your second as 
$$ y = x \left( y' - W(\exp(y')\right) $$
(where $W$ is the Lambert W function), and your third as
$$ y = x \;\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{(y')^2+1}}{y'} $$